# Camel Producer blocks when AMQ queue in separate process fills up

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic

I have two separate Spring Boot apps using camel - lets call them `producer` and `consumer`.

In the `producer` process, the camel `ProducerTemplate` sends messages to `activemq:queue:consumer`

In the `consumer` process, listens to that queue.

When I kill the `consumer` process, and I can see in the AMQ console that there are no consumers of the queue, the `producer` sends about 1000 messages to the queue, and then blocks.

If I purge the queue, the `producer` unblocks and processes about another 1000 messages, and then we repeat.

Why is the `producer` process backing off if the downstream queue gets backed up? And how do I fix this?

I am using `Spring Boot 1.5.6`, `Camel 2.18.0` and `Apache activemq 5.11.0.redhat-630187`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like your broker is using Producer Flow Control, which basically means that the producer will be blocked from sending more messages than the broker can handle. To remedy this you can enable Message Cursors which will write the messages to disk, thus delaying a block until all the allocated disk space has been filled up.

You can read more about Producer Flow Control [here](http://activemq.apache.org/producer-flow-control.html), and Message Cursors [here](http://activemq.apache.org/message-cursors.html).